# Nginx is active but serving only intermittently, no errors

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, https, gunicorn

I am attempting to serve a simple html page with django, gunicorn and nginx. There is something wrong because very often my domain is showing the domain provider's ad, not my page. It works for brief periods before it seems to stop working by itself. While I was writing this post, I changed nothing on my server and it began serving my page then immediately stopped again. I am accessing the domain with browser caching disabled and private windows. Sometimes, the www server will show correctly and the non-www will not, and vice versa.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Here is my sites-available:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/example/project/staticfiles;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/sockets/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

`sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log` returns no errors.

`sudo nginx -t` shows configuration file is OK and test is successful.

I have enabled nginx in systemctl. `systemctl status nginx` returns

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-12-11 22:21:27 EST; 5min ago
```

gunicorn systemctl service is likewise running.

If I modify sites-available/example.com to

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 200 "it works";
}
```

then `systemctl restart nginx`, nothing changes, I'm still looking at the domain provider's ad page.

`cat /var/log/gunicorn/error.log` returns a normal log, no errors. Restarting gunicorn with systemctl did nothing.

SSL_certs were made using certbot. They are correct, as the page works normally for brief moments.

`netstat -tulpen | grep 80` shows listening on 80 and same with port 443

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20990      718/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          20991      718/nginx: master p
```

`lsof -i -n | fgrep nginx` returns

```
nginx      718            root    5u  IPv4  20990      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx      718            root    6u  IPv6  20991      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx      718            root    7u  IPv4  20992      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx      718            root    8u  IPv6  20993      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx      720        www-data    5u  IPv4  20990      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx      720        www-data    6u  IPv6  20991      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx      720        www-data    7u  IPv4  20992      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx      720        www-data    8u  IPv6  20993      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx      720        www-data   13u  IPv4  74558      0t0  TCP 138.197.26.3:http->65.154.226.169:7976 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx      721        www-data    5u  IPv4  20990      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx      721        www-data    6u  IPv6  20991      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx      721        www-data    7u  IPv4  20992      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx      721        www-data    8u  IPv6  20993      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

`curl -I https://example.com` shows

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 03:45:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 147
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=3600; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

`curl -I http://www.example.com` shows as expected the redirect

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 03:46:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/
```

`ufw status` is
`Status: inactive`

Restarting the VM did nothing. It is a digital ocean VPS. Ubuntu 23.10. Please help me understand what I can check or log to understand why the nginx server seems to be flickering.

Comment: Do you know for sure the problem is in nginx? If you `curl -k https://localhost`, do you have the same issue? Do your nginx logs show access when you get the wrong result? Could it be that your domain is load-balanced, so you get your nginx half the time, and some other machine the other half?

Comment: (obviously, you'd need to enable [`access_log`](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#setting-up-the-access-log) to check if there was access)

Comment: @Amadan curl -k https://localhost shows the expected page. At the moment, access_logs are showing as expected for the www server. The non-www server is not being served and does not show up in access logs.

Comment: I don't believe the domain is load balanced. I didn't set that up, provider doesn't indicate any load balancing. Provider is godaddy. All system charts look normal on the server, CPU, IO, network are all normal.

Comment: If `localhost` always responds correctly, it is obvious that the problem is outside your server, definitely not in `nginx`. Just in case, try `nslookup` on your domain name. If you see two different IPs...

Comment: Ok we're getting somewhere. nslookup is showing 3 IP addresses. The last one is my server's public IP, two I don't recognize. Visiting the two unknowns show the domain provider ad. Visiting the public IP of my server shows the unconfigured nginx page "Welcome to nginx!" Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `nslookup` shows multiple IP addresses, you basically have [DNS load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) in effect, whether intentionally or not.  It is probably a misconfiguration. You need to talk to whoever set up your DNS record, as only they can fix it.

(I believe the reason why your IP is responding with an unconfigured nging page when you use the bare IP is, your nginx is configured with `server_name example.com`, so contacting it with bare IP does not trigger the `server` configuration you want. You would need to list your IP in `server_name` to get the desired response to an IP URL. See [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) docs, in particular the "Miscellaneous names" section.)

Comment: Thank you so much, you were absolutely right it was a misconfigured DNS record

Comment: Specifically I had duplicate A records